# HighStock charts - Change default Open Price to Close Price

Tags: highcharts

I am learning to use Highstock charts. I pass OHLC data, but when I use
type: 'line'
the chart displays Open Price.  I understand Open is the first element after date, but is this configurable to change to Close?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is configurable. You can parse your data to display only the `close` values.

```
Highcharts.getJSON('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlcv.json', function (data) {

        const lineData = data.map(d => d[4]);
        

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            data: lineData
        }],
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a6dtL8hw/